# Click on element behind image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am facing some problems with my current system.

Check this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q221O.jpg
I want to "click" behind the avatar to get the "item" (table) behind him. But i cannot, because of the picture is overlapping.

Here you can see the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM6nA.jpg

How should i do this? It is impossible? Or do i have to make it in HTML5 Canvas to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the overlapping picture trigger his `parent()` click event. For example :

```
$('#myImage').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: I should also be available to rightclick on the "overlapping" picture, only the places where the image is transparent i should be available to catch the parent image. But is this possible?

Comment: if it should behave like there is no overlapping, you should use a background image instead of an overlapping picture

Answer (score 2):

Best way should be to use only CSS for this:

```
#avatarDiv{pointer-events:none;}
```

**UPDATE**

Following this comment,

> I should also be available to rightclick on the "overlapping" picture,
>   only the places where the image is transparent i should be available
>   to catch the parent image.

**this is no more a solution.**

Comment: note IE and opera not support. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: It doesn't seem to work properly. Would canvas fix this issue?